# Can not use SSMS object explorer to connect to 2019 SSRS. (rept server config mgr / rsreportserver.config file mismatch?)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

After installing SQL Server 2019 & SSRS 2019 developer editions, I am not able to use the object explorer in SSMS to connect to SSRS. (I am also unable to use a web address to open SSRS currently due to my security software.)  I think the reason I can't use SSMS is due to one or more of the following:

- an error in installation
- problems with older version files still left on the computer
- an error in using the report server configuration manager
- the rsreportserver.config file not getting properly updated.

Before installing 2019 developer editions, I have installed and tried to uninstall most versions since 2012, including 2019 express & evaluation.  When I tried to install 2019 evaluation software, I created a new db engine (MSSQLSERVER02) while installing SQL Server.  After I installed SSRS, I used the report server configuration manager to use this new engine as the database).  This tested correctly.  I opened up SSMS & connected to this db engine.  When I tried to go to SSRS, the only option was a previous db engine (MSSQLSERVER01).  Though I put the new name in the config mgr, there still existed an rsreportserver.config file which had the old db engine (MSSQLSERVER01) and a coded database name.

When I uninstalled the eval ed., then installed the dev versions, I still had the same problem with the old db engine (MSSQLSERVER01) name appearing.  When I chose the older db option, I get a lengthy error:
Cannot connect to LAPTOP-999999\MSSQLSERVER01. Unable to connect to the server at LAPTOP-999999\MSSQLSERVER01. The specified URL might not be valid or there might be a problem with the report server version or configuration. Specify a different URL, or contact your server administrator to verify that the report server runs SQL Server 2008 or later. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient)

When I type the the new db engine (MSSQLSERVER03) over the old, I get an error: "TITLE: LAPTOP-999999\MSSQLSERVER03 cannot be found.The Reporting Services instance could not be found. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient)

I also tried putting in the web address into the server name (suggested by DeanOC in a similar question).

Any direction on what to do next would be greatly appreciated!

thanks,
Ginger Burton
c

Comment: I just opened the report server configuration manager and when I went to select a server, only the old SSRS server name "SSRS" was available.  This is not something I set in recent installs know----=-

Comment: Oops!  I just opened the report server configuration manager and when I went to select a server, only "SSRS" was available.  This is not something I set in recent installs knowingly..  I don't know if "SSRS" is an old SQL db engine or something else related to SSRS specifially.  (It is in the rsreportserver.config file actually.  I had changed the names to try to simplify, but it was not a good idea.)  Ginger Burton